# How do I get role name for user in dnn?

Tags: c#, asp.net, dotnetnuke

I am new programmer in DNN. My question is How do I get role name for user in DNN?

My code is:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    int UserId = UserController.GetCurrentUserInfo().UserID;
    int PortalId = PortalSettings.PortalAlias.PortalID;

    UserInfo user = UserController.GetUserById(PortalId, UserId);
    String[] array = new String[5];

    for (int x = 0; x < 5; x++)
    {
        array[x] = UserInfo.Roles.ToString();
    }
    TextBox1.Text = array[0];
    TextBox2.Text = array[1];
}
```

But just display `System.String[]` in textboxes.
What should i do?

Comment: `array[x] = string.Join(", ", UserInfo.Roles);`

Comment: thank you so much.my problem is resolved

Comment: If you want to check if a user has a specific role you can use `if (PortalSecurity.IsInRole("roleName") == true) { }`

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code:

```
String[] array = new String[5];
var user = UserController.GetUserByName(UserInfo.Username);
for (int x = 0; x < user.Roles.Count(); x++)
{
 array[x] = user.Roles[x];
}
```